# how to iterate on column in pyspark dataframe based on unique records and non na values

Tags: pyspark

I have below code in python

```
for i in (map.area.unique()):

   # Select all the map records from the currently processed area
   f_0 = f_map[(f_map['area'] == i )]
   m_0 = m_map[(m_map['area'] == i) | (m_map['area'] == "Unknown")]
```

I am rewriting it in pyspark. But the third line is throwing exception. Can anyone point out what I doing wrong.

map dataframe is :

```
             play_id    calendar_period            telephone  area
 1:         286178          201811                03235095  510
 2:         286179          201811                03235113  500
```

f_map:

```
       id        value area type
1: 227149 385911000059  510  mob
2: 122270 385911000661  100  fix
```

```
m_map:
       id area type
1: 227149 590  mob
2: 122270 190  fix
```

Ouput should be :

```
       id        value    area type
1: 227149 385994266007 Unknown  mob
2: 122270 385989281716 Unknown  mob
```

Comment: What are you trying to find when you write `sampdf['area'][i] == i`?

Comment: its unique values of area code, so i is my each value of area code which will be unique

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem arises from the last line. If I understand your problem correctly, this should be what you're looking for:

```
 temp1 = sampdf[(sampdf['area'] == i) | (sampdf['area'] == "Unknown")]
```

Comment: yeah but it throws error  " Lengths must match to compare" for this line.
 I believe 
```for (i in unique(df[!is.na(area)][order(area), area]))```
I am doing wrong here too